# when i created scroll view like this it's not working why...?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I created scroll view like this but its not working why i don't know please help me.when i did like this i'm getting error like this:Exception raised during rendering: Scroll View can host only one direct child.please help me how can i solve this problem .
        enter code here

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.jeshtamsru.tntrains.DashboarsActivity">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:width="300sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="chennai to coimbatore"/>
</RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:width="300sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="chennai to coimbatore"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You have two `RelativeLayout` s inside the `ScrollView` `ScrollView` can contain only one child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Scroll view then it allows only one direct children. And as per how it works, it scrolls the  child which is getting more space than available.
In your scenario Relative layout is not taking too much space to support scroll. And their are some basic errors in your layout also, like never give a button width in sp.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.jeshtamsru.tntrains.DashboarsActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RelativeLayout
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                 <Button
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:width="300dp"
                      android:gravity="center"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="chennai to coimbatore"/>
         </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:width="300sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="chennai to coimbatore"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

**Scroll View can host only one direct child** error itself says everything.

You have taken 2 `RelativeLayout` inside `ScrollView`, it must have **atmost one child**.

> A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in
>   it containing the entire contents to scroll

[reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Comment: Ok then how can i do this i want to dis play more number of buttons in scroll view

Comment: take a `LinearLayout` or any other layout and add your child in that, but `ScrollView` must have only one child.

Comment: @chandu You can put more than one button in a single layout. Using a new layout for each control is unnecessary and wastes resources. Put all your buttons into one layout and put that layout into a ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

**Scroll View can host only one direct child**

Wrap your layouts inside your scrollview inside a relative or linear layout.

```
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <RelativeLayout
      ... (stuff you had inside your ScrollView)
   </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```